# trouble selecting FROM WHERE?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code, but strangely it always echos out "yes!", even if there is no such value as '555' in FLD2 or even if there's no FLD2 at all.

```
$testresult = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM imei359327039828680 WHERE FLD2 = '555'");

if ( $testresult ) { echo('yes!'); } else { echo('no!'); }
```

Any idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned by **ctshryock**, a variable set to the returned value of a well-formed SQL query will always be seen as **true** when reviewed as a boolean object.

To test whether any data was returned, you could use `mysql_num_rows()`[PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) which will return the number of rows returned. If your query would not match any rows, then this function should return **0** which would be seen as **false** by an `if()` condition.

```
$testresult = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM imei359327039828680 WHERE FLD2 = '555'" );

if( !$testresult )
  die( 'SQL Error' ); # The SQL Query Failed for some reason

if( mysql_num_rows( $testresult ) )
  die( 'SQL Returned No Result' ); # The SQL Query returned nothing

while( $r = mysql_fetch_assoc( $testresult ) ) {
  # Process your returned rows here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query` always returns a result object unless the query fails somehow. If the query just doesn't return any rows, you still get a result object; it just won't have any rows in it.

Comment: THNAKS, now it works!

$testresult = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT * FROM imei359327039828680 WHERE FLD2 = '555'");
$testrow = mysqli_fetch_array($testresult);
if ( $testrow ) { echo('yes!'); } else { echo('no!'); }

Answer (score 1):

You're testing if `$testresult` is true, not if their are the expected results of the query.  If the query is valid, i.e. well formed, it will return a valid object.  You want to look into the `$testresult` return value to see if you found something or not.